# Quaternion division not equal to multiplication with inverse (q1 / q2 != q1 * q2^-1)?

Tags: matlab, multiplication, division, quaternions, inverse

From several docs, like [[1]](http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/People/kindr/emtc/quaternions/) and [[2]](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/arithmetic/index.htm), I learned that divide operation on a quaternion is equivalent to multiply its inverse. That is to say, for two quaternions **q1** and **q2**, we have

[image]

However, when I verify this in MATLAB, which will give different results (also verified by further converting them to rotation matrix via `quat2rotm`). See code below:

```
q1 = [1 0 1 0];
q2 = [1 0.5 0.5 0.75];
q1 = quatnormalize(q1);  % this seems doesn't matter
q2 = quatnormalize(q2);  % this seems doesn't matter

res_1 = quatdivide(q1, q2)               % this will be [0.7385  0.1231 0.2462 -0.6155]
res_2 = quatmultiply(q1, quatinv(q2))    % this will be [0.7385 -0.6155 0.2462 -0.1231]
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried **q**_2^(-1) **q**_1 ? `quatmultiply(quatinv(q2), q1) =  ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that quaternion division leads to an ambiguous notation.

reading from [your 2nd reference](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/arithmetic/index.htm) it states

[image: lem]

To expand upon this see what the result of the two interpretations are:

[image: fgi1]

They differ by the sign of the cross product in the vector part.

I suspect that `quatdivide()` uses the 2nd convention such as

```
quatdivide(q1,q2) = quatmultiply(quatinverse(q2),q1)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is confirmed in `quatdivide` official implementation, i.e., `quatdivide( q, r ) = quatmultiply(quatinv( r ), q)`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao my guess this is done to be consistent with matrix division which is `x/A = inv(A)*x`.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Your comment seems backwards. If you start with Ay = x and then solve for y you would get y = A\x or y = inv(A)*x, which would give A\x = inv(A)*x.